# jsp code always shows error at result set?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, server

I get an error as shown below

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1fyw.png)

My code is:-

```
String query="insert into student(stdid,sname,branch,email,phone)values(' "+htno+" ',' "+sname+" ',' "+branch+" ',' "+email+" ',' "+phone+" ')";
Statement stm=con.createStatement();
rs=st.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: 1. I doubt the code shown is responsible for the error. 2. post the stacktrace as text, not as screenshot. 3. you are **very** open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: my complete code is available at https://pastebin.com/knTeWJw9 and stack trace at https://pastebin.com/R4Fjy9qp

Comment: what about `cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."STUDENT"."STDID")` do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Statement then change line to

```
String query = "INSERT INTO student(stdid,sname,branch,email,phone) VALUES (\'" +
    htno +
    "\', \'" +
    sname +
    "\', \'" +
    branch +
    "\', \'" +
    email +
    "\', \'" +
    phone +
    "\')";
```

But I recommend you to use PreparedStetement to protect your applicaton from SQL injections, then your query will look like this:

```
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement();
    String SQL_CREATE_STUDENT = "INSERT INTO student(stdid,sname,branch,email,phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    st.setInt(1, id);
    st.setString(2, sName);
    st.setString(3, branch);
    ...
```

read more :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: my complete code is available at https://pastebin.com/knTeWJw9 and stack trace at https://pastebin.com/R4Fjy9qp

Answer (score 0):

With the minimal information available all i can say is , if the "con" object is null then while calling the "con.createStatement();" a null pointed exception would be thrown.

Please share more details to troubleshoot this further.

---

Thank you for sharing the logs and the code, it is helpful to analyse the issue. I have gone through the stack trace and the application code.
Below mentioned code snippet assigns the value of stdid

```
String htno = request.getParameter("stdid");
```

The code fails with Nullpointer exception while executing below line

```
ResultSet rs2=pst2.executeQuery();
```

The stack trace shows below error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."STUDENT"."STDID")
```

The above message indicates that value provided for STDID is null. This is the cause of the error. If you debug and check the value of "htno" you can verify this.

Comment: my complete code is available at https://pastebin.com/knTeWJw9 and stack trace at https://pastebin.com/R4Fjy9qp